# How to share 'UserContext' across multiple spring-boot microservices module?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, microservices

I have multiple **spring boot microservices** like

```
 - admin-service
 - api-gateway
 - eureka-server
 - auth-service
 - context-server
 - business-service
```

Here: I want to share **'User Identity'** (for example: *username*), managed by **context-server** across all other microservices for **Auditing** purpose. Which apparently I am not able to. Any suggestions to what I'm missing so that i can create a sharable *usercontext* microservice?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how you can preserve the user identity in downstream microservices. Here are two of them:

1) Use [Spring Session](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session). It gives you the ability to distribute a user session across microservices by simply adding a dependency.

2) Pass the original user's token to downstream calls and have the same Spring Security configuration there.

In both cases, you will be able to get a username from [SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if using 'Spring Session' is a good idea for a RESTful Web application. And passing user's token to downstream calls and have the same spring security configuration could be an expensive architectural decisions. Any other alternatives @Dmitry Sergeev?